# roscore killing on exit error

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed fuerte a few days ago and removed electric because I messed with something and wasn't running properly anymore.

Upon typing roscore, ROS seems to startup but then, I get an error message saying something along the lines of:

Error: could not contact master [http://ubuntu:11311]
[master] killing on exit

I'd really appreciate some help with this. Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33125/roscore-killing-on-exit-error/) by [mte2010](https://answers.ros.org/users/2294/mte2010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2012-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your environment variables are probably not set up correctly. Try:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

You should also check that `ROS_ROOT` and `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` are set up correctly for fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1